# Hexagon style table columns

Tags: html, css

is it possible to make the top columns of the table where the column names are put in this genre?
[image]

This is my code:

```html
<table class="" style="background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); font-size:15px;  border-collapse:separate;
                             border:solid yellow 3px;
                             border-radius:6px;
                             -moz-border-radius:6px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      @if ($service->id == 13)
      <th scope="col">PROJECT</th>
      <th scope="col">Execution PERIOD</th>
      <th scope="col">GLA(SQM)</th>
      <th scope="col">Project Value</th>
      <th scope="col">Project Functions</th>
      @endif
    </tr>
  </thead>
  @foreach ($data as $dataItem)
  <tbody>
    @if ($dataItem->service_id == $service->id)
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{ $dataItem->project }}</th>
      <td>{{ $dataItem->execution_period }}</td>
      <td>{{ $dataItem->SQM }}</td>
      @if ($dataItem->project == 'Total')
      <td style="font-weight:bold; color:green;">{{ $dataItem->project_value }}</td>
      <td style="font-weight:bold; color:green;">{{ $dataItem->project_function }}</td>
      @else
      <td>{{ $dataItem->project_value }}</td>
      <td>{{ $dataItem->project_function }}</td>
      @endif
    </tr>
    @endif
  </tbody>
  @endforeach
</table>
```

Is it possible what I think or is it complicated?
I don't know exactly what I could do in css, I'm not a very good front

Comment: I would solve it with the use of a svg. However its not tabular data and no table should be used. use flexbox instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My attempt using a more meaningful markup.

You can use `display: flex` and the `gap` property to align the menu items with the proper spacing.

To change the bevel effect just change the value of the variable `--bevel`

```css
ul {
   list-style:none;
   display: flex;
   gap: 2px;
}

li {
   --bevel: 14px;
   padding: .75rem 1.5rem;
   color: gold;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
   clip-path: polygon(
        0 var(--bevel), 
        var(--bevel) 0, 
        calc(100% - var(--bevel)) 0, 
        100% var(--bevel), 
        100% 100%, 
        0 100%
   );
}
```

```html
<nav>
   <ul>
      <li>lorem</li>
      <li>lorem ipsum</li>
      <li>consectetur dolor</li>
      <li>amet</li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: So, can I use this on table? Is very good <3